# android:background not working

Tags: android, background

I'm learning Android programming, and am having a problem when I want to add a Background Image to an Activity that says `hello android` (The default app when we create a project). I tried with way smaller images and it worked, but I want to use a big image, and when I use that big image, it doesn't work on my device, which is Samsung Galaxy Grand Duos.

I'm using the `android:background="@drawable/my_big_image"` inside the `activity_main.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/a_real_big_image"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The image is png, and its dimensions are 1688x1464.
I put that image in every single folder that says drawable.

Do you know how to solve this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Each image is about 9.8MB!  You didn't say what "doesn't work means", but I'm guessing out of memory.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object)

Comment: @Simon correct - bitmaps occupy a lot of memory: 1688X1494 * 4 = 9.9 MB. I suggest user3220206 to study this link: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: It doesnt show up, like if i didnt put a background image.

Answer (score 0):

Try resizing the image using paint or other software to somewhere around 400px width and try if the image then shows up.

Also try cleaning and building your project again.